# Why DOM came into picture?

Tags: dom

I understand DOM is document object module which is used for create and modify html document or xml document but what exactly DOM will do?

IF DOM is not there then what will happen?

Comment: This is too broad. You need to learn the history then.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is extremely broad. There's a zillion things the DOM does, and it would be far too long to answer you. Instead, please make some research and come back when you want to ask about specific features. Plus, your title, "Why DOM came into picture?", is hardly answerable because it asks for **reasons**, not for **facts** and it would be hard to answer (except by the DOM creators themselves). You need to read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to understand why you can't ask such things on SO.

Comment: Sure Kyll, i ll read guidlines as i am new here so not aware of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOM is a structural and very organized way of presenting an HTML (or XML) document in an OO way. It sort of glues components to scripts, languages, styles. In other words, it gives an standard protocol to deal with documents.

It is just a data representation and a good one. DOM opens up document contents to for  manipulating its components as we see fit. Without DOM, we would have to parse the document again and again and it would have been time consuming (I am talking about SAX parser here).